# SQLAlchemy: Perform double filter and sum in the same query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a general ledger table in my DB with the columns: `member_id`, `is_credit` and `amount`. I want to get the current balance of the member.

Ideally that can be got by two queries where the first query has is_credit == True and the second query is_credit == False something close to:

```
credit_amount = session.query(func.sum(Funds.amount).label('Debit_Amount')).filter(Funds.member_id==member_id, Funds.is_credit==True)

debit_amount = session.query(func.sum(Funds.amount).label('Debit_Amount')).filter(Funds.member_id==member_id, Funds.is_credit==False)

balance = credit_amount - debit_amount
```

and then subtract the result. Is there a way to have the above run in one query to give the balance?

Comment: Take a look at [hybrid attributes](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/extensions/hybrid.html) and also keep in mind you could use `group_by` to get both amounts in one query.

Comment: Are you only expecting to have one database entry for credits and debits? Or are there multiple?

Comment: @javex am really a newbie in SQLalchemy and python in general so that link about hybrid is really complicated at this point. Can you illustrate the `group_by` option? @Greg not sure about your comment but one transaction can yield several credits and debits so in this case they are multiple. Also, its my general ledger table so all transactions have to hit this table. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

From the comments you state that hybrids are too advanced right now, so I will propose an easier but not as efficient solution (still its okay):

```
(session.query(Funds.is_credit, func.sum(Funds.amount).label('Debit_Amount')).
 filter(Funds.member_d==member_id).group_by(Funds.is_credit))
```

What will this do? You will recieve a two-row result, one has the credit, the other the debit, depending on the `is_credit` property of the result. The second part (`Debit_Amount`) will be the value. You then evaluate them to get the result: Only one query that fetches both values.

If you are unsure what `group_by` does, I recommend you read up on SQL before doing it in SQLAlchemy. SQLAlchemy offers very easy usage of SQL but it requires that you understand SQL as well. Thus, I recommend: First build a query in SQL and see that it does what you want - then translate it to SQLAlchemy and see that it does the same. Otherwise SQLAlchemy will often generate highly inefficient queries, because you asked for the wrong thing.